# Java compare time with timezone

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

My table has a column whose datatype is timestamp with timezone. The value in database is something like

- `26-NOV-01 12.00.00.000000000 PM -07:00`
- or `26-NOV-01 12.00.00.000000000 PM -08:00`

I have a tomcat server which is running in the UTC timezone. I know how to compare two dates which have the same timezone, but I am unable to figure out if I can compare server time with db time which have timezone details like `-7.00`, `-8.00` or `+5:30`.

Is there a way in java to convert a time from database to common timezone and then compare it to another time?

Comment: Look at Joda DateTime. It is very powerfull arround all DateTime Questions. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Hm, how do you read the db values? JDBC does not support sql-columntype TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE, at least not before Java 8. The class java.sql.Timestamp is only compatible with TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE.

Comment: @dognose JodaTime is good but cannot do magic here and has its own limitations.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I'm confused by your statement of WITH TIMEZONE vs WITHOUT TIMEZONE. Both types store the same value, neither has time zone information (the name "WITH TIMEZONE" is something of a misnomer). The difference is how they handle inputs that include time zone info, where "WITHOUT TIMEZONE" means any specified time zone indicator is ignored during parsing and the date-time assumed to already be in UTC. "WITH TIMEZONE" means attention is paid to inputs tz and adjustment to UTC is performed. So both types should behave the same in terms of JDBC and java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: @BasilBourque Hi, my statement is related to ANSI-SQL. JDBC cannot do really more than map available SQL to Java and actually does not support SQL option "WITH TIMEZONE". The mapping is: java.sql.Date <=> DATE, java.sql.Timestamp <=> TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE, java.sql.Time <=> TIME WITHOUT TIMEZONE. What SQL labels as TIMEZONE is in common Java understanding rather an offset. Java 8 will offer new db mappings using OffsetTime and OffsetDateTime. JodaTime does NOT offer these two new types.

Comment: @BasilBourque ...  Of course, one thing JDBC can do is to map every db column type to String making any kind of implicit string conversion (that is what PopoFibo is trying and which might go as workaround).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`joda-time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to conveniently parse your offsets and dates to a common on (say UTC).

Taking the example of the 2 time instances mentioned in your post:

```
String time1 = "26-NOV-01 12.00.00.000000000 PM -07:00";
String time2 = "26-NOV-01 12.00.00.000000000 PM -08:00";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa Z").withZoneUTC(); // joda time date time formatter instance with a common UTC timezone

System.out.println(parser.parseDateTime(time1)); // parse to date time - gives: 2001-11-26T19:00:00.000Z
System.out.println(parser.parseDateTime(time2)); // parse to date time - gives: 2001-11-26T20:00:00.000Z

System.out.println(parser.parseDateTime(time2).compareTo(parser.parseDateTime(time1))); // Comparing both the times here - gives: 1
```

Here, you are able to compare the 2 times with different offsets and normalize them to a common timezone. Similarly, you can choose the timezone of your choice and work these time instances conveniently.